# Why would I want to build more floors?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

Ultimately, tower bux and red/white chips are the valuable currency of this game. From what I can tell, these are the only free ways to get more chips:

- Fulfill quests
- Take people on the elevator

Both of these get harder the more floors you have. Wouldn't it make more sense to just keep the tower really really small until I have tens of thousands of chips, and only then grow the tower larger?

Comment: Hiring bitizens in their dream jobs also provides 1 free chip each time, which is much easier to do when you have a wide variety of floors.

Answer (score 1):

Some missions payout more chips the more floors you have. When your mission is to find something (objects or bitizens), you get one chip for every 20 floors you have.

So floors 1-19: one chip
Floors 20-39: two chips
Floors 40-59: three chips, etc.

In addition, while floor costs increase logarithmically, [the floor tip bonus increases exponentially](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197026/what-is-the-tip-received-at-each-floor-on-tiny-tower-vegas). It's not a huge money-maker, but it can help bring in coins short-term.

Comment: So, Nimblebit has been watching SE then?

Comment: Also, this still doesn't encourage me to build more floors, because even though you get more chips for those events, the event itself takes much longer than if I only had 3-4 floors.

Comment: @CoryKlein I totally agree with you. I was just pointing out that, as far as I know, there is at least one benefit of having more floors. Whether or not that is worth the extra costs incurred is up to you!