# What is the tip received at each floor on Tiny Tower Vegas?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

While I really like the cute visual of exploding coins and (sometimes) chips when transporting a Bitizen up the elevator, unlike with Tiny Tower (coin = 2*floor level), I can't easily determine how much coin I'm getting for each elevator tip.

I do know that when you transport a Bitizen to a fully stocked casino floor, you will receive a chip. I don't know if that's above and beyond the regular tip you get for transporting them to their floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 29-floor tower and decided to calculate this myself after clearing out all of my stock. The tip has a linear relationship with floor number and is:

```
t = 3.75*f + 50.4
```

Where t = amount of tip in coins, and f is the floor number. **The coin tip is independent of whether or not you also receive a chip as part of the tip! (So if a Bitizen goes to the 4th floor and tips a chip and coin, you will receive one chip and 65 coins.)**

The following table shows the amount of tip received for floors 2-29.

Floor - Tip
2 - 58
3 - 62
4 - 65
5 - 69
6 - 73
7 - 77
8 - 80
9 - 84
10 - 88
11 - 92
12 - 95
13 - 99
14 - 103
15 - 107
16 - 110
17 - 114
18 - 118
19 - 122
20 - 125
21 - 129
22 - 133
23 - 137
24 - 140
25 - 144
26 - 148
27 - 152
28 - 155
29 - 159

[image: Graph showing the amount of tip for each floor from 2-29.]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the tip is calculated as tip=speed*10*floor*(gold+1)
Where speed is the elevator speed, floor is the floor number, and gold is the number of gold bux you have.  When you start you have no (zero) gold bux and an elevator speed of 1 foot/sec. so if you had a ride to the 10th floor (I use 10 because multiplying b 10 is easy) your tip is 100. As you increase your elevator speed your tip goes up linearly. Now start increasing your gold bux and your tip rate really starts increasing. With 99 gold bux (again easy multiplication 99+1=100) the same 10th floor ride yields a tip of 10,000. Hope this helps